# Good practice for implementing a device based subscription in a website

Tags: authentication, cookies, web

I need to limit the number of devices a user can use to log on my website.

In time he may update his browser, so this must not affect the authentication.
He may change his ip or share his ip with others.
He could also change the browser or delete the cookies, but those cases are to hard to cover.

It's also important that the validation is not too easy to circumvent. eg.  clone cookies

It needs to work on both desktop and mobile.

I know there are many options available, like using a combination of cookies and user agent. I want to know what would be the best practice to approach this.